# The number of parameters in Gaussian mixture model

Tags: machine-learning

I have D-dimensional data with K components.
How many parameters if I use a model with full covariance matrices?
and How many if I use diaogonal covariance matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [xyLe_](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/125463/xyle) at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229321/127305

Simply do the math.

For each Gaussian you have:
1. A Symmetric full *DxD* covariance matrix giving `(D*D - D)/2 + D` parameters (`(D*D - D)/2` is the number of off-diagonal elements and `D` is the number of diagonal elements)
2. A *D* dimensional mean vector giving `D` parameters
3. A mixing weight giving another parameter

This results in `Df = (D*D - D)/2 + 2D + 1` for each gaussian.
Given you have *K* components, you have `K*Df` parameters.

In the diagonal case the covariance matrix parameters reduce to `D`, because of the abscence of off-diagonal elements.
Thus yielding `Df = 2D + 1`.